# minecraft plugin to arduino over a serial connection

Tags: java, c, arduino, minecraft

I am trying to send from minecraft with the command /arduino a message over COM4
(the port where my arduino is on) the message has to be "allesfade"
I got it working with just java but not in minecraft.

Here is my code(not working)

```
package me.PixelHamster.idk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.comm.SerialPort;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

static SerialPort basispoort;

public void onEnable() {
System.out.println("suc6vol aangezet :3");
}

public void onDisable() {
System.out.println("sec6vol afgezet :3");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender zender, Command cmd, String label, String[] argument) {
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("arduino")) {
try {
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(basispoort.getOutputStream());
output.print("allesfade");
output.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}




}
return true;
}
}
```

here is the code just in java that I wrote which works.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

public class Main {

static SerialPort chosenPort;

public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setTitle("Arduino Kleurenzender");
window.setSize(600, 75);
window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Sound.HAM.play();

JComboBox < String > portList = new JComboBox < String > ();
JComboBox < String > kleurselector = new JComboBox < String > ();
JComboBox < String > wat = new JComboBox < String > ();
JButton connectButton = new JButton("aan");
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.add(portList);
topPanel.add(kleurselector);
topPanel.add(wat);
topPanel.add(connectButton);
window.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

SerialPort[] portNames = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++)
portList.addItem(portNames[i].getSystemPortName());
kleurselector.addItem("groen");
kleurselector.addItem("geel");
kleurselector.addItem("rood");
kleurselector.addItem("blauw");
kleurselector.addItem("alles");
wat.addItem("aan");
wat.addItem("flikkeren");
wat.addItem("fade");
connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
if (connectButton.getText().equals("aan")) {
chosenPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(portList.getSelectedItem().toString());
chosenPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
if (chosenPort.openPort()) {
connectButton.setText("uit");
portList.setEnabled(false);

Thread thread = new Thread() {
@Override public void run() {

try {
Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (Exception e) {}


PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(chosenPort.getOutputStream());
while (true) {
output.print(kleurselector.getSelectedItem() + "" + wat.getSelectedItem());
output.flush();
try {
Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Exception e) {}
}
}
};
thread.start();
}
} else {
chosenPort.closePort();
portList.setEnabled(true);
connectButton.setText("aan");
}
}
});

window.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

the error in the console

> '4/04/2016 21:19:49 [INFO] PixelHamsters issued server command: /arduino
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 [ERROR] null
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'arduino' in plugin Arduino v1.0.0
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot 1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:645) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1302) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1137) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_31]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_31]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:716) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:655) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:554) [spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_31]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at me.PixelHamster.idk.Main.onCommand(Main.java:34) ~[?:?]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot-1.9.jar:git-Spigot-7d15d07-c194444]
>
> 4/04/2016 21:19:49 ... 15 more'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersting project :)

I would say that the problem is that it is a plugin. A plugin runs on the server and not on the client side. So you would need to connect the arduino to the server. If you want to control a arduino from minecraft you're gonna need a mod (which runs on client side) for minecraft.

IDK if that would work.

Another way could be to connect the arduino to the Internet (Shield, or with a Raspberry pi) and then let the plugin (which runs on the server) send a Message to that shield/pi over the internet.

sry for bad english :(

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok but im trying to make it first work just on a local server